# Getting outer environment arguments from java using graal python

Tags: java, python, graalvm

I'm running Java in a GraalVM to use it to execute python.

```
Context context = Context.create();
Value v = context.getPolyglotBindings();
v.putMember("arguments", arguments);

final Value result = context.eval("python", contentsOfMyScript);
System.out.println(result);
return jsResult;
```

The question is how the python code should receive "arguments". The graal documentation states that if this were JS, I would do something like this:

```
const args = Interop.import('arguments');
```

Indeed, that works. The python equivalent might be:

```
import Interop
args = Interop.import('arguments')

def main():
    return args

main()
```

This fails, as there's no such module. I can't find documentation on how to get these arguments from the outer language layer, only docs on pythongraal and how to use python to pass to something else.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some information on this is available at http://www.graalvm.org/docs/reference-manual/polyglot/.

The module you're looking for is called `polyglot`.
The operation is called `import_value` in Python, because `import` is a keyword.

You can import from the polyglot bindings using the following:

```
import polyglot
value = polyglot.import_value('name')
```

btw, it's almost the same in JavaScript: `Polyglot.import(name)` (`Interop` still works, for compatibility reasons)

A complete example:

```
import org.graalvm.polyglot.*;

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Context context = Context.newBuilder().allowIO(true).build();
        Value v = context.getPolyglotBindings();
        v.putMember("arguments", 123);

        String script = "import polyglot\n" +
                        "polyglot.import_value('arguments')";
        Value array = context.eval("python", "[1,2,42,4]");
        Value result = context.eval("python", script);
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  You're pointing me back to the same documentation I was looking at before, and what I'm realizing with the benefit of your answer is that the libraries are no different whether the language is host or guest.  I had been thinking I was looking at irrelevant examples where python was the host, which wasn't what I wanted.

Comment: @FrobberOfBits To simplify this example you may also write directly into a top scope of the language bindings:
`context.getBindings("python").putMember("arguments", 123)`
In Python you can directly access `arguments` as if it were a variable in the top-most scope. E.g.
`context.eval("python", "arguments + 42")` works.

Comment: @ChristianHumer I have tried using the approach you suggest here to use the top scope bindings with Python. However I get the following error even when reproducing the exact example you posted: org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: java.lang.AssertionError: Returned scope variables object must be a TruffleObject. Using polyglot bindings works fine. What could be the issue? thanks.

Comment: @edoDev GraalPython is still early and experimental so certain features are not yet implemented. I think this issue is already fixed in a newer version. Which version are u using? Otherwise please report a bug to the GraalPython repo.

Comment: @ChristianHumer I am running "Graal Python 3.7.0 (GraalVM CE Native 1.0.0-rc4)". Should I file a bug report?

Comment: Can you please retry with RC5 first? There are good chances it was fixed already. Otherwise, yes please.